# JQuery - count the number of i with fa fa-star

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  $(".rate i").css('cursor', 'pointer');
  $(".rate i").click(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).prevAll("i")).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
    $(this).nextAll("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    console.log($(this).closest('.rate').data('target') + ': ' + $('input[name="' +     $(this).closest('.rate').data('target') + '"]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rate Us:

<div class="row rate" data-target="form-rate-instructor">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Instructors: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-rate-instructor" value="3">
</div>
<div class="row rate" data-target="form-rate-surrounding-environment">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Surrounding Environment: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-rate-surrounding-environment" value="3">
</div>
```

I have that snippet code for the rates, I wanted that every time the value of the rates changes the target input which is hidden will also be change, the default value on load is 3, so i put 3 as well in the hidden `input`, now I wanted to get all the `i` that has `fa fa-star` like if I have 2 `fa fa-star` only the value on the input that is targeted will also be changed. How will I do that?

Comment: You can use $(this).index() to get which li is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code

```
$($(this).parent().parent().find("input")[0]).val($(this).parent().find(".fa-star").length)
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".rate i").css('cursor', 'pointer');
  $(".rate i").click(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).prevAll("i")).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
    $(this).nextAll("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    $($(this).parent().parent().find("input")[0]).val($(this).parent().find(".fa-star").length)
    console.log($(this).closest('.rate').data('target') + ': ' + $('input[name="' + $(this).closest('.rate').data('target') + '"]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rate Us:

<div class="row rate" data-target="form-rate-instructor">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Instructors: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-rate-instructor" value="3">
</div>
<div class="row rate" data-target="form-rate-surrounding-environment">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Surrounding Environment: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o text-info"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-rate-surrounding-environment" value="3">
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks mate I literally forgot `.length` darn it, I will make this the correct answer later on 4 minutes

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this snippet to take all the siblings of your current clicked i element and add your selcted i count to get the number of all selected i elements

```
$(this).siblings('i.fa.fa-star').length + 1
```